# how to get the ascii value for integer greater than 127 (extended Ascii character) in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ascii, stringwithformat

I need to send the Ascii value for an integer greater that 127 to an external device. I'm using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c", myInteger]`. However, this return an empty string probably because myInteger is greater than 127, e.g 155.

How can I get the correct Extended Ascii value?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the ASCII value for an integer greater than 127".  But note that `@"c"` is not going to do anything beyond print the letter "c".

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII" do you mean ISO8991-1 or UTF8?

Comment: Linuxios. I'm not sure what I mean. In my world there is a so-called Extended Ascii character set with integer values between 127 and 255, e.g 155 = ø. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `%C`, not `%c`. Then it will work with any 16-bit value.

Comment: Actually, he wasn't using `%c`, he was using `c`.

Comment: I assumed that was a typo.

Comment: Sorry - a typo. I have used %c and also have tried with %C but there seems to be no difference. I was not able to use %C directly. Xcode requires me to use this [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c", (unitype) myInteger].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant, but I have been playing around with characters for a c++ text-based game I am making. Keep in mind that I am working on CMD.

I used this to get all the possible characters, to know what I have to work with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256;i++) {
        cout << i << " " << char(i) << endl;
    }
```

You can use     int(character) to do the opposite.

Like "user1152964" said, this must be the Extended ASCII, because after 255, all the characters just repeat themselves.

In my opinion, your best choice would be to send the integer value of the character you want to send to the external device and then make sure that the character is presented in the right format.

This might help you with Objective C:
[Objective-C int to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590853/objective-c-int-to-char)